# Is it mandatory to give four references in post-doctoral positions?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, recommendation-letter

I have just started applying for a few postdoctoral positions in mathematics. Sometimes through a particular university portal and sometimes through the job portal [mathjobs](https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs?joblist-----40).

But the problem is that sometimes it is asking for four references, and the referees will receive email links in order to upload their letters. I have managed to get consent from four professors. But if I apply for 20 positions, suppose, then they will need to upload their letters 20 times, which seems very disturbing to those busy professors. This is why I am planning to give 2-3 references alternatively so that their task gets reduced. So:

Is it okay to give three references instead of four? I guess it should be optional

How would postdoctoral candidates manage such situations?

Comment: For the positions through mathjobs: ask the referees to upload a “generic” letter, then select that on each job you are applying for. So each letter writer receives just one link total. For mathematics postdoc applications your letter writers will almost certainly not personalise their letter for each position.

Comment: Interfolio also has an option to ask for a generic letter.

Comment: @AruRay, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess that you reduce your chances slightly if you do this. Some, not all, might wonder why you didn't submit the "expected" number. It might even be an unconscious bias.

Let your letter writers know how many places you will be applying to so they have a "heads-up" on the situation. They can manage, possibly, in some cases, with staff help.

If you are applying for a lot of positions, I recommend that you don't use "boilerplate" applications, but tailor them to the institution. More work for you, but, again, you want to maximize the chances for consideration.

Comment: +1 for this! The most time-consuming part for the letter writers is writing the original recommendation. Adjusting it afterwards for different places is a minimal cost that can be alleviated by providing them with a clear list (spreadsheet?) of the different places with relevant info for each (name, deadline etc.).

Comment: Most of the US math postdoc positions I saw during my application season in 2019 request some variant of 3, maybe with some leeway up to 4 for a teaching letter. My point is just that 4 research letters seems like a rare request that doesn't so much matter at this level.

Comment: @leonos In mathematics it isn't expected that letter writers adjust their letter at all. I have been involved in multiple hires, and seen well over a thousand rec letters, and I believe only one of them was tailored.

Comment: @academic You have to update the name of the university and the job description the person is applying to, surely? Or do you mean all math recommendation letters are addressed to “to whom it may concern” and have no mention of the place the person is applying to?

Comment: @leonos The latter. For e.g. an NSF postdoctoral fellowship or for a recommendation for a nonacademic job, letters should probably be tailored at least somewhat. But for academic jobs this is not expected, even superficially.

Comment: I've even been on TT hiring committees where we still consider a good applicant missing a letter. Though we just send out a request for it. Anyone else have that experience?

Answer (score 17):

Don't do this. There is no significant difference between having to upload a letter 20 times and having to upload a letter 15 times.

You would in fact be doing your references a disservice: they spent their time writing what they hoped would be an effective letter, and your proposal is to go and make their effort possibly go to waste by needlessly shooting yourself in the foot like this. If I spend my time writing a letter for you, the more mileage you can get out of it the better (even if it involves spending a couple of extra minutes on my part uploading it).

If the position asks for X letters, just upload X letters and don't overthink it.

Comment: Seriously, yes.  Particularly at the post-doctoral level people writing reference letters are generally positively invested in the success of the former students they are writing for.

Answer (score 7):

> How would postdoctoral candidates manage such situations?

What I have seen, in mathematics specifically, is candidates using Interfolio as a dossier service to manage their letters. As a writer, I then only have to upload to Interfolio, and then the candidate can have it sent wherever they wish.

Comment: Some universities use interfolio but many use other systems, like UC recruit, etc.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I haven't used Interfolio as a candidate, so I don't know precisely how it works on their end, but my understanding is that it can be configured so that Interfolio sends the letters to UC Recruit and so on.

Comment: Interesting: I also used interfolio only as a letter-writer and I did not know they work with other systems. I will check this out.

Comment: @academic, if I understood well, interfolio recommendation letter means a pre-prepared generic letter by a referee which he/she will upload to the system generated link everytime. Is it? If yes, i already gave such ideas to the referees.

Comment: @learner It does mean a pre-prepared generic letter, but the writer does not need to upload it every time. I'm afraid I don't know the technical details, but as the applicant you do something on your end, ask the writers to upload to Interfolio once, and then you are able to do all the tedious scut work and not ask your referees to do it.

Comment: @academic, I get it. You are right. I just saw that one of my referees has uploaded a generic letter for one position, and it is automatically switched to other applications as well. It is solved now.

Comment: Does interfolio work with mathjobs?  I think in math, most positions in the US still use mathjobs.

Comment: @Kimball No, so when I say "upload once" I really mean "upload twice". ;) Although it seems that, in math, an increasing number of universities don't use mathjobs. I assume this is invariably at the insistence of administrators, over the objections of math departments.

Comment: @Kimball Well, contrary to what I just said, I think Interfolio *will* work with mathjobs, but my advice to OP would be to ask letter writers to submit to both, as that's what candidates seem to do in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to reach out directly to the head of the group. Write a short but informative email with your view on the subject, if the position comes from the grant, maybe a sentence or two why your skills/PhD fits the grant subject etc.
It is always better to "put your foot in" instead of being 76th person that sent a generic request.

Making a connection might also help you explain why you are not able to provide necessary documents/references (without the bias that other answer wrote about).

If you have published in similar topic, they could have cited you and that would open another avenue. I'm on my second postdoc and in both times they were familiar with my work already so this improved my chances significantly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information. Can you please share your experience? I mean, how many positions did you apply for before getting an offer?

Comment: I've sent 4 applications for my first postdoc and about 20 for my second (because I wanted to stay in the country where I was so I applied to groups that weren't a very high match). Sending references was usually the last step and more of a formality, when it was more or less decided that I'll go to this or that place.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience. It gives me some motivation